How to get rid of obsolete APIv4 Extension from Extensions Admin Page?
How do I get rid of this from my extensions page? Not a big deal, just OCD is triggered by it.



Click the little triangle. At the bottom of the accordion that opens it will tell you the file path to where it lives. Delete those files. You might then need to also click the refresh button at the top of the extensions page.

unfortunately, as you can see from the new screenshot, thats not something I can do. :)

Interesting. In the database, do you have an org.civicrm.api4 in your civicrm_extension table? Can you delete that row?
